# 2020 Survey ambiguity: Which platforms have you done extensive development work in

Tags: discussion, survey-2020

This question in the 2020 Developer Survey is ambiguous:

"*Which platforms have you done extensive development work in over the past year, and which do you want to work in over the next year?*" The checklist includes Android, AWS, Linux, Mac, Windows, etc.

Does this question refer to **writing code that runs on the specified platform** (for example, writing an Android app), or does it mean **using the platform to write code for any other platforms** (for example, using a Mac laptop to write code that will later execute on Linux)?

I would be interested if the question were indeed split into two: (1) what platform(s) do you write software on? (2) what platform(s) do you write software for?

Comment: indeed, I interpreted it as a generic "what do you use" and I kind of ignored the usage of the word "platform" in that assumption.